# garbage collector not working?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

my JDK version is 1.7.0_25

```
class A { 
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("deleting...");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("main class");
    }
}
```

i expected the out put as

```
deleting...
main class
```

but in my case there were no output what is the reason ? and when i compile and run the code online with JDK 1.7.0_09 then the outputs are ,

```
main class
deleting...
```

why the "main class" prints first ?

Comment: The GC never guarantees when the the clean up happens, finalize() may be or may not be called, by doin `System.gc();` you are only requesting the GC to be invoked but its up to the JVM to fulfill your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC never guarantees when the the clean up happens,

```
finalize()
```

may be or may not be called.

By doin `System.gc();` you are only requesting the GC to be invoked but its up to the JVM to fulfill your request.

`Will the System.gc() invoke the cleanup?`

The answer varies depending on lots of factors, like which JVM you're running on, which mode it's in, and which garbage collection algorithm it's using.

I wouldn't depend on it in your code. If the JVM is about to throw an OutOfMemoryError, calling System.gc() won't stop it, because the garbage collector will attempt to free as much as it can before it goes to that extreme.

So... if there is anything that you would want to perform for certain, do not write that code in `finalize()`

Answer (score 1):

It is not specified when finalization will happen.  The *only* thing that is specified / guaranteed is that finalization will happen before a finalizable object is actually deleted from the heap.

In practice, finalization is typically done by a special finalization thread that gets notified when the main GC thread finishes its work.  It looks like control is returning to the main thread before the finalization thread gets to process the object.

Basically, you cannot rely on the order in which these things happen.  And that is one of the reasons why depending on finalization to do things is generally a bad idea.

And besides, it is not even guaranteed that the `System.gc()` call will do anything.

---

In short, what you are observing is "within the envelope" of specified behaviour for finalization.  The garbage collector is working.  It is your expectations that are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee whether  finalize() method will be called or not when you call `System.gc()` method. Go throgh java API. And for the second question , main() method is a thread. And when you call garbage collector , it will be executed in another thread.So if you understand threads , by now you will know the answer (You can't predict thread execution order)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers corrrectly stated that there is no way to make sure finalizers are run. I just wnated to add something concerning the question about the execution-order:

When a GC detects an object with a `finalize()`-method is to be deleted it doesn't delete it right away but first puts it on the finalization-queue. After that GC is finished and the application resumes working the VM will start running all queued finalizers - that should explain the order of your output. Only after that can the object actually be GCed.